Upload file to firebase cloud function for further process on file using typescript?
I am trying to upload a file, and then after want to perform some operations on the file, which I am uploading to this function using this CURL:
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/{PROJECT_ID}/us-central1/fileProcess' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/kishan/Downloads/C8tjkue6Ao.pdf"'

Here's my cloud function, which is written in node.js typescript:
import * as express from "express";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions/v1";
import {Fields, Files, IncomingForm} from "formidable";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp();
}

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false, limit: "50mb"}));

app.post("/", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void => {
  console.log("[INFO] Received request:", req.method);
  console.log("[DEBUG] Request Headers:", req.headers);

  const form = new IncomingForm({
    keepExtensions: true,
    multiples: true,
    uploadDir: '/tmp' // Explicitly set upload directory
  });

  // Add progress tracking
  form.on('progress', (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) => {
    console.log(`[DEBUG] Progress: ${bytesReceived}/${bytesExpected} bytes`);
  });

  // Add error event handler
  form.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('[ERROR] Form error:', err);
    res.status(500).send({message: 'Error processing form'});
  });

  // Add file event handler
  form.on('file', (name, file) => {
    console.log('[DEBUG] Received file:', name, file.originalFilename);
  });

  try {
    form.parse(req, (err: Error | null, fields: Fields, files: Files): void => {
      console.log("[DEBUG] Inside form.parse callback.");

      if (err) {
        console.error("[ERROR] Failed to parse form:", err);
        res.status(400).send({message: "Error parsing form data"});
        return;
      }

      if (!files || !files.file) {
        console.error("[ERROR] File is required");
        res.status(400).send({message: "File is required"});
        return;
      }

      const fileData = Array.isArray(files.file) ? files.file[0] : files.file;

      if (!fileData.originalFilename) {
        console.error("[ERROR] File has no original filename");
        res.status(400).send({message: "Invalid file data"});
        return;
      }

      console.log("[INFO] Uploaded file name:", fileData.originalFilename);

      res.status(200).send({
        message: "File uploaded successfully",
        fileName: fileData.originalFilename,
      });

      console.log("[SUCCESS] File handled successfully");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("[ERROR] Exception in form parsing:", error);
    res.status(500).send({message: "Internal server error"});
  }
});

export const fileProcess = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '1GB' // Increase memory allocation
  })
  .https.onRequest(app);

but I am ended up with this below output such as timeout case and others:
>  [INFO] Received request: POST
>  [DEBUG] Request Headers: {
>    'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.43.0',
>    accept: '*/*',
>    'postman-token': '36ff596e-6822-4f80-b628-7da73efcbea1',
>    host: '127.0.0.1:5001',
>    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
>    connection: 'keep-alive',
>    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------430674860192243674092838',
>    'content-length': '4720'
>  }
>  [DEBUG] Progress: 0/4720 bytes

Nothing is happening below at this line:
form.parse(req, (err: Error | null, fields: Fields, files: Files): void => {


does the tmp folder exist, next to the main file

@traynor doesn't affecting whether the "uploadDir" param passing or not...
